# PowerShell Security Log

Tags: security, powershell, event-log, event-id

I am writing a PowerShell Script that counts the number of 4624 EventIDs in a given day, but I am getting lost when I go to group the information by date.  Is there anyone who could help me out?  My output should have the date and the number of Logins for that day and nothing more.

Here is my Code:

```powershell
Get-EventLog "Security" -Before ([DateTime]::Now) |
    Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-EventLog Security -Before ([DateTime]::Now) | 
    Where {$_.EventID -eq 4624} | 
    Group @{e={$_.TimeGenerated.Date}} | 
    Sort Count -desc
```

The `Group-Object` command allows you to specify an expression for the property to group on.  In this case you want to group on the `date` part of the DateTime.  Also note that it is unnecessary to quote arguments unless they contain space or special characters like `;`, `@`, `{`, `$` and `(`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew I was missing something small from the code I was using.